# Products custom option stock status

Tags: custom-options, stock

I premise that I'm a newbie with Magento.
I have to insert some products in my shop (shoes, specifically) and I use drop-down as custom option to do select the size.
So, when I select "dropdown" as custom option, as values I can insert "title", "price", "price type", "sku" and "sort order".
Is there any way to add "availability" field for each size?
Thanks guys!
Giacomo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom options have no stock information.  Please consider configurable products instead. It's a bit harder to create them, but they gives you full control over inventory and prices.

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product  also